# Maximal set of mutually skew lines in a finite projective space

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields, projective-geometry, projective-space, finite-geometry

What is the maximum size of a set of mutually-skew lines in a finite projective space?  The total number of lines in a finite projective space is well-known ($(q^2 + 1)(q^2 + q + 1)$) and mentioned in many places, including the Wikipedia page "Finite geometry".  I am sure that the size of a set of skew lines has long been known, and I saw it on a web page yesterday, but today, realizing that I need the answer, I can't find any online reference.  I am hoping that somebody knows the reference off the top of their head.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but A) What is the dimension of the projective space over $\Bbb{F}_q$ you are looking at? B) What are *mutually skew lines*?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen From the number $(q^2+1)(q^2+q+1)$ of lines I concluded that the question apparently is about a narrow-sense space (i.e. geometric dimension 3).

Comment: Thanks, @azimut. Obvious now that I had the time to write down a few lines of arithmetic :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I used "space" without qualification, meaning 3 dimensions.  "mutually skew lines" means a set of lines any two of which are skew.  "skew" has the same definition as in ordinary geometry, they do not intersect and they do not lie in the same plane.  In 3-space, this means that their "join" is the entire space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in $\operatorname{PG}(3,q)$ there exist so-called *spreads*, which are sets of mutually skew lines covering all points. Hence, the number you asked for is $q^2 + 1$.

The standard construction is the *Desarguesian spread*. Take the set $S$ of all $q^2 + 1$ one-dimensional subspaces of the $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$-vector space $V = (\mathbb{F}_{q^2})^2$ (i.e. all points of the projective line over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$). By the concept of field reduction, we consider $V$ as a 4-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
Then $S$ is a set of $q^2 + 1$ two-dimensional subspaces of $V$ with pairwise trivial intersection. Hence $S$ is a spread in $\operatorname{PG}(V) \cong \operatorname{PG}(3,q)$.

Comment: Thanks!  Interesting that it works out so easily.  I constructed a set of $q^2$ lines almost trivially, having little knowledge of projective geometry, and yet was only 1 short of the maximum.

Comment: @Dale By a so-called "stability result", the remaining $q+1$ points (not covered by a line) of your configuration should form a line, and thus can be added to your line set as the last missing line to form a spread. My guess is that this spread will be isomorphic to the Desarguesian spread, as it is the most regular one.